How do I display multiple OpenGraph preview images when my page is shared?
I found an example of a site that, when shared on iMessage and Discord, displays two OpenGraph images stacked on top of each other. How do I replicate this on my site? For reference, I am using Next.js.

Side question, would multiple OG images affect SEO?
I tried having two og:image meta tags in my header, but it only showed one.

Search engines like Google primarily consider the first og:image tag. Having multiple images won't directly affect SEO, but some platforms (like iMessage and Discord) might choose to display them differently. In this case, two  declarations are used that point to two different images.
<meta content="https://assets-global.website-files.com/653addd11146228383e8c898/65f862402767ace193668e73_OG%20Image.jpg" property="og:image">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://assets-global.website-files.com/653addd11146228383e8c898/65a6ee96199882d0ec374116_Opengraph%20(5).jpg">
